# Creating table layout in React Native app

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a table layout in my React Native app and I think I'm pretty close but rows seem to spread out over the whole screen. I'd like the table and all its rows to stay at the top of the screen. I tried `flex-start` but didn't seem to help. Also, notice that I really would like the white background to show in between columns. In my code, all the columns merge into one.

Here's the outcome I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

And here's a [link to my snack](https://snack.expo.io/@imsam67/table-layout) where you can see and play with the code and here's the code as it is now -- see below:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.tableContainer}>
        <View style={styles.tableRow}>
          <View style={styles.tableColumnHeader}>
            <Text style={styles.textHeader}>Monday, February 6, 2021!</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.tableRow}>
          <View style={styles.tableColumnRegular}>
            <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>10:00 AM</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.tableColumnRegular}>
            <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>12:00 PM</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.tableColumnRegular}>
            <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>2 Hrs</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.tableColumnRegular}>
            <Text style={{...styles.textLineItem, justifyContent: "flex-end"}}>$25.00</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.tableRow}>
          <View style={styles.tableColumnRegular}>
            <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>1:00 PM</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.tableColumnRegular}>
            <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>5:30 PM</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.tableColumnRegular}>
            <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>4.5 Hrs</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.tableColumnRegular}>
            <Text style={{...styles.textLineItem, justifyContent: "flex-end"}}>$56.25</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.tableRow}>
          <View style={styles.tableColumnHeader}>
            <Text style={styles.textHeader}>Tuesday, February 7, 2021!</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.tableRow}>
          <View style={styles.tableColumnRegular}>
            <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>9:00 AM</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.tableColumnRegular}>
            <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>12:00 PM</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.tableColumnRegular}>
            <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>3 Hrs</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.tableColumnRegular}>
            <Text style={{...styles.textLineItem, justifyContent: "flex-end"}}>$37.50</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.tableRow}>
          <View style={styles.tableColumnRegular}>
            <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>1:00 PM</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.tableColumnRegular}>
            <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>5:30 PM</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.tableColumnRegular}>
            <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>4.5 Hrs</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.tableColumnRegular}>
            <Text style={{...styles.textLineItem, justifyContent: "flex-end"}}>$56.25</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
    padding: 8,
  },
  tableContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  tableRow: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: "white"
  },
  tableColumnRegular: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    backgroundColor: "#c7c7c7",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: 25,
    padding: 2
  },
  tableColumnHeader: {
    flex: 4,
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: "tomato",
    height: 25,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  textHeader: {
    color: "white"
  },
  textLineItem: {
    color: "black"
  }
});
```

I'd appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I hope this solution helps others too. Obviously, I changed the colors from the original specs but that would be easy to update if someone else were to use this code.

Here's the [link to my snack](https://snack.expo.io/@imsam67/table-layout).

And here's the code:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.tableContainer}>
               <View style={styles.tableRowHeader}>
                  <View style={styles.tableColumnHeader}>
                     <Text style={styles.textHeader}>Monday, February 8, 2021</Text>
                     <Text style={styles.textHeaderSubTitle}>(6.5 Hrs)</Text>
                  </View>
               </View>
               <View style={styles.tableRow}>
                  <View style={styles.tableColumnClockInOutTimes}>
                     <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>10:00 AM - 12:00 PM</Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.tableColumnTotals}>
                     <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>2 Hrs</Text>
                  </View>
               </View>
               <View style={styles.tableRow}>
                  <View style={styles.tableColumnClockInOutTimes}>
                     <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>1:00 PM - 5:30 PM</Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.tableColumnTotals}>
                     <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>4.5 Hrs</Text>
                  </View>
               </View>
               <View style={styles.tableRowHeader}>
                  <View style={styles.tableColumnHeader}>
                     <Text style={styles.textHeader}>Tuesday, February 9, 2021</Text>
                     <Text style={styles.textHeaderSubTitle}>(8 Hrs)</Text>
                  </View>
               </View>
               <View style={styles.tableRow}>
                  <View style={styles.tableColumnClockInOutTimes}>
                     <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>8:30 AM - 12:00 PM</Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.tableColumnTotals}>
                     <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>3.5 Hrs</Text>
                  </View>
               </View>
               <View style={styles.tableRow}>
                  <View style={styles.tableColumnClockInOutTimes}>
                     <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>1:00 PM - 5:30 PM</Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.tableColumnTotals}>
                     <Text style={styles.textLineItem}>4.5 Hrs</Text>
                  </View>
               </View>
            </View>
         </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      backgroundColor: "#000000",
      flex: 1,
      padding: 10
   },
   tableColumnHeader: {
      alignItems: "center",
      backgroundColor: "#1FE0A2",
      flex: 5,
      justifyContent: "center"
   },
   tableColumnClockInOutTimes: {
      alignItems: "center",
      backgroundColor: "#000000",
      flex: 3,
      justifyContent: "center",
      margin: 1
   },
   tableColumnTotals: {
      alignItems: "center",
      backgroundColor: "#000000",
      flex: 2,
      justifyContent: "center",
      margin: 1
   },
   tableRow: {
      flex: 5,
      flexDirection: "row",
      maxHeight: 30
   },
   tableRowHeader: {
      flex: 5,
      flexDirection: "row",
      maxHeight: 40
   },
   tableContainer: {
      backgroundColor: "#202020",
      borderRadius: 5,
      flex: 1,
      marginTop: 0,
      padding: 10
   },
   textHeader: {
      color: "#000000",
      fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    textHeaderSubTitle: {
       color: "#000000",
       fontSize: 12
    },
    textLineItem: {
      color: "#FFFFFF"
    }
});
```